# Changed Int to uniqueidentifier in a Database Project

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-project

I would like to change a primary key column from `int` to `uniqueidentifier` in a database project. I tried to change the type but got predictable error because SQL Server can't convert `int` to `guid`. ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4LB2.png)):

```
+ ------------ + -------------- + ----------- + ------- +
| Name         | Data_Type      | Allow Nulls | Default |
+ ------------ + -------------- + ----------- + ------- +
| OrderImageId | int            | No          |         |
| OrderId      | int            | No          |         |
| Image        | varbinary(MAX) | Yes         |         |
| FileName     | nvarchar(Max)  | Yes         |         |
+ ------------ + -------------- + ----------- + ------- +

create table [dbo].[OrderImages]
(
    [OrderImageId] int not null primary key identity,
    [OrderId] int not null
        Constraint [FK_OrderImages_Orders] foreign key (OrderId) references [Orders]([OrderId]),
    [Image] varbinary(Max) null,
    [FileName] nvarchar(max) null
)
```

I know how to do it in SQL Server Management Studio (create a separate guid column, fill it, delete PK, set PK for guid column etc), but is it possible to do it in a database project? And what if my PK column has FKs?

Answer (score 2):

To do this you will need to create a new table and migrate the data, substituting the guids that you want to use to replace the existing integer data.

That being said, using a uniqueidentifier here is not a good idea.  It is 128 bits of essentially random data that will cause fragmentation.  If you expect to have more than 4 billion images with possibly multiple images per order, you can use a bigint.

If there will be no more than one image per order, you can use the OrderID as the primary key (without the identity constraint) and avoid needing to add a nonclustered index on OrderID.